# Insert into field if the field is NULL mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, time, null

I am trying to check if a value column is null then insert a value into it based of a series of if statements, my only problem is I don't know what the value of null actually is in PHP.

I have checked that the id_created is being echo'd out, and the first insert script is working but it seems there is  problem with my if statement:

```
if (isset($_POST['ra'])){
        $db->query('INSERT table (`lid`, `id_created`, `call_start`) VALUES ('.intval($_GET['id']).','.intval($_SESSION['user']['id']).',NOW())');
        if ($_SESSION['user']['id'] == $calllogs['id_created']){
            if ($calllogs['call_end'] == 'Null'){
                $db->query('INSERT INTO table (`call_end`) VALUES (NOW()');
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: `$calllogs['call_end'] == null`

Comment: A null value in PHP is just `null`, not `'Null'`, the quotes turn it into a string. Also see the [documentation on NULL](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php). You can also use the [is_null()](http://php.net/is_null) function to check if a variable has a null value.

Comment: I assume these 2 queries are on the same table, So I think you want to UPDATE and not INSERT to add the `call_end` information

Comment: You are going to have to show more of the actual code from before this section if you want any really useful help rather than a set of **guesses**

Comment: You should also get into the habit of `testing for errors` after each call to any database API. Stuff goes wrong while you are developing. If you test for errors and display the error message provided by the API, you will get places faster and be able to diagnose your own mistakes!

Comment: **WARNING**: Using manual escaping is extremely error prone and a single mistake can lead to a crippling [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.